# Why won't my event fire?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get an event to fire on anchors within an unordered list. My goal is to have the event report anytime someone has clicked on any of those anchors, doesn't matter which one. All anchors within the menu have the ID "cos-anch". Here's the list code:

```
<li><a id="cos-anch" href="#teeth_whitening">Teeth Whitening</a></li>
<li><a id="cos-anch" href="#porcelain_veneers">Porcelain Veneers</a></li>
<li><a id="cos-anch" href="#bonding">Cosmetic Dental Bonding</a></li>
<li><a id="cos-anch" href="#white_fillings">Tooth-Colored (White) Fillings</a></li>
<li><a id="cos-anch" href="#gum_lifting">Cosmetic Gum Contouring (Gum Lifting)</a></li>
<li><a id="cos-anch" href="#smile_makeover">Smile Makeover (Smile Design)</a></li>
```

I defined the trigger as "Click - Just Links." I set the trigger condition as Click ID equals cos-anch. Yet when I use either Preview mode or publish to my site, my event won't fire. How can I make this work?

Comment: Because those are anchor links maybe?

Comment: Make sure that "check validation" in the trigger is not checked (as GTM will not consider in-page anchors valid links). Unrelated, but you need to fix your ids (they are supposed to be unique within the page).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Check validation is not checked and hasn't been, but thank you. So how do I do this with multiple IDs? I can give each anchor a unique ID but then how do I put that as a condition? Is there a way to have the event fire if only one of the conditions is fulfilled?

Comment: Either use a class instead of id or append a suffix (cos-anch-1, cos-anch-2 etc) and use "starts with" as condition. I don't think this will solve your particular problem, but the purpose of the "id" atttribute is to identify a specific element (which it doesn't if multiple elements have hte same id). Bit of background here, including links to the relevant specifications:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id